# Unchecked call and Unchecked assignment java factory generics

Tags: java, generics, warnings

Consider the following scenario:

```
public abstract class A {}

public class B extends A {}

public interface Provider<T extends A> {
    List<String> list(T param);
}

public class ProviderB implements Provider<B> {
    @Override
    public List<String> list(B param) {
        return Collections.singletonList("ProviderB");
    }
}


public class Factory {
    public static Provider get(int x) {
        if (x == 1)
            return new ProviderB();
        throw new RuntimeException("Not supported");
    }
}


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Provider provider = Factory.get(1);
        A a = new B();
        List<String> result = provider.list(a);
    }
}
```

In Main at `List<String> result = provider.list(a);` , I'm getting:

```
Unchecked call to list(T) ..
Unchecked assignment java.util.List .. Reason 'provider' has raw type.
```

I do know some basic stuff about type erasure in generics. How would you solve the warnings ?

**EDIT:**
Actually main will look like this:

```
public static void main(Map<Integer, ? extends A> types) {
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, ? extends A> entryType : types.entrySet()) {
            Provider provider = Factory.get(entryType.getKey());
            List<String> result = provider.list(entryType.getValue());
        }
    }
```

Comment: You've painted yourself into a corner. If you don't know what type of `Provider` the factory returns, you can't know what type of `T` to pass to `list()`. It would help if you explain what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: `public static Provider<? extends A> get(int x) {` and `Provider<? extends A> provider = Factory.get(1);` should fix this. - well, except you get an error on `provider.list(a);`, because `a` is an `A`, but only some (unspecified) subclass might be accepted.

Comment: @shmosel take a look at the usecase

Comment: @JohannesKuhn `Provider<?>` should work just as well.

Comment: @cehptr Who's enforcing the relationship between key and value type?

Comment: Seems like generics is only overcomplicating your solution.

Comment: The scenario is more complex, but they are related. So I should support somehow this behavior.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn using `<? extends Something>` is better suited for argument rather than for return type.

Comment: What you expect to do cannot be achieved using generics like that. Maybe you'd need to pass a specific class to know which kind of provider to get instead of having it all abstract.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/2891664 for why we shouldn't use raw types (such as `Provider` with no type argument) in new code. You should change all uses of `Provider` to `Provider<?>`, but this will move the unchecked warning to a compilation error. The new code won't compile because there's a more general problem, which is that you don't know what the actual type of the returned provider is, so passing things to its `list` method is unsafe according to the compiler. I think we need to know more about what you're actually doing to suggest a real solution.